# How do I create different sets of settings at run time?

Tags: wpf, settings

My WPF application has a bunch of settings the user can adjust, I am using the built-in application settings (Properties.Settings... and a .settings file) to do this and it all works fine. Now, the application is supposed to allow the user to define different presets of settings for different purposes (different samples to be exact, it's a measurement system software) so they don't need to go over every setting again when they switch.

So, I would need to be able to create copies of the application settings at runtime and save them all separately in their own file, then restore them when the application starts up. I can create new settings files at design time but that's outside of the user's control and not what I am looking for. I also can create new Settings instances in code but when I save them it just overwrites the same user.config file the default instance used and the Save() method takes no arguments to save it somewhere else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a separate class for your preset settings. Then you can save this as a list in Settings.

So lets say you have a preset class that holds your settings values:

```
public class Preset
{
    public int MaxPower { get; set; }
    public int AllowedRotations { get; set; }
}
```

You could in one place get all of these settings like so:

```
var presets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Preset>>(Properties.Settings.Default.Presets);
```

And you would save the settings like so:

```
List<Preset> presets = null;
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Presets == null)
    presets = new List<Preset>();
else
    presets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Preset>>(Properties.Settings.Default.Presets);

presets.Add(new Preset() { AllowedRotations = 1000, MaxPower = 200});

Properties.Settings.Default["Presets"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(presets);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I guess you can also have some kind of unique ID for these objects so you can differentiate one preset from the other.

**NOTE**: I am using Json converter here and saving the list of objects as JSON.

Comment: I just couldn't make VS accept my custom settings class as a settings data type no matter what I tried so in the end I just abandoned the whole Application Settings feature and did the serialization myself. Your approach generally works, thank you.